# resetAuth() not called for connectors with AuthType.NONE

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

Why is `resetAuth` function not called when revoking credentials for Google Data Studio Community Connectors with `AuthType.NONE`? I store some values in `PropertiesService` for every user and would like to erase them once they revoke the access to the connector. I don't get it why for example for `AuthType.OAUTH2`connectors `resetAuth` is called but for `AuthType.NONE` it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid use case that is currently not supported. `resetAuth()` won't get called for `AuthType.NONE`. You can [make a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=345845&template=1162971) for this.

In the meantime, I suggest using `AuthType.KEY`, instructing your users to put in any value for `KEY`, returning `true` for `isAuthValid`, and then using `resetAuth()` to remove the values from `PropertiesService`. Not the cleanest solution but a potential workaround.